# windows 8.1 no sound from HDMI monitor

Tags: audio, windows-8.1, display, hdmi

Is there any way to get the sound through the monitor without starting them both together?

If i turn on the PC with the monitor plugged in, it plays sound through the monitory correctly.

But if the PC is already on, and gets plugged into the monitor, there is no way to get the sound through the HDMI.

Is there anyway to do this without restarting the PC?

Comment: @K7AAY you are way overthinking this. Its just a matter of windows not automatically switching to a newly installed audio device automatically.

Answer (score 1):

When you connect a monitor over HDMI, and turn it on after windows is loaded, windows will install the drivers for the audio, but not automatically switch to it.

To switch audio, simply click your speaker icon, and at the top, click the device. A popup shows you all listed devices. Select your HDMI audio device and sound will go play through your speakers from that point forward.